# Подменить контент при помощи js

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, есть код html:

```
<div class="cat_service">Наименование:
<span>Доски</span>  <span>Стулья и столы</span> 
</div>
```

Можно ли подменить контент вместе со span, именно с `<span>Доски</span>` на `<span class="doski">Доски</span>`, а если будет `<span>Стулья и столы</span>` на `<span class="stulya_i_stoly">Стулья и столы</span>`?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.cat_service span').forEach((span) => {span.classList.add('что-вам-там-надо');})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    window.onload = function () {
        var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
        for(let i=0;i<spans.length;i++){
            if (spans[i].innerHTML == "Доски"){
                spans[i].classList.add('doski');
            } else if (spans[i].innerHTML == "Стулья и столы") {
                spans[i].classList.add('stulya_i_stoly');
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<style>
    .doski{
        color: #b61924;
    }
    .stulya_i_stoly{
        color: blue;
    }
</style>

<div class="cat_service">Наименование:
    <span>Доски</span>  <span>Стулья и столы</span>
</div>
```